# How to fix role in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to use Spring Security in my project, here is the code:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.configure(auth);
    //auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("1111").roles("USER");
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, 1 from users where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select users_username, roles_id  from roles_users where users_username=?")
            .rolePrefix("ROLE_");
}   

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable();      
    http
        .httpBasic();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users/all").hasRole("admin")
            .and()
        .formLogin();
    http
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
}
```

Here is the problem:

Imagine we have two users (one with the `user` role and the other one with the `admin` role) in our database one admin and the second is a user, the problem is when I connect as user (which has only `user` role) it can access to admin resources (and this is not the expected behavior).

I think the problem in this query:

```
"select username, password, 1 from users where username=?"
```

According that `username` is the primary key?

If anyone has an idea how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 13):

Your first matcher [`anyRequest()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#anyRequest--) is always applied, because the order of matchers is important, see [`HttpSecurity#authorizeRequests`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeRequests--):

> Note that the matchers are considered in order. Therefore, the following is invalid because the first matcher matches every request and will never get to the second mapping:
>
> ```java
> http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").antMatchers("/admin/**")
>             .hasRole("ADMIN")
> ```

Your modified and simplified configuration:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()      
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users/all").hasRole("admin")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the reference to the original documentation, this is not in the reference guides with the same clarity IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with the ordering of your rules when you configure your `HttpSecurity`.  What's happening is when the request comes in and hits the

```java
authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
```

and since the user is authenticated it never makes it to the

```java
.antMatchers("/users/all").hasRole("admin")
```

Here is an example of how you can configure it:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()      
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/public").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .and()
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
}
```

It uses the chain of responsibility pattern.  It will go through the chain of rules until it finds a rule that matches.  Any rules that come after the rule that matches are never reached.  Generally when writing the rules for authenticated requests, the more specific rule will come first.