# Role based authorization - unable to give root URL for anonymous

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

The below setup allows anonymous user to access restricted `antMatcher`s defined below. I tried placing `/**` at end of this chain and still not able to solve this.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").not().anonymous()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").not().anonymous()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/owner/**").access("hasRole('OWNER')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
  }
```

I wish a setup with authorization.

1. `/**` for anonymous
2. `/admin` for admin users
3. `/owner` for owner users
4. `/user` for other users

Authentication with specific roles are working fine.

**Edit:**  If I give `/browse/**` to allow anonymous user, I can allow as I wish. But I don't want to see browse pattern in the URL as I am delivering pages through Spring MVC and makes me to move my pages to under `/browse` URL pattern.

How to deliver pages in Spring MVC for any user without any pattern match in the beginning of URL like browse or something? Can I use static and public folders under resources to deliver such pages? Good practice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix role in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052745/how-to-fix-role-in-spring-security)

Comment: without mentioning any antmatcher, is there any way to allow all users other than /admin, /owner and /user ? I know we can put /public to all anonymous users to be allowed. I don't want to go with that.