# How to enable spring security for particular url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

im using spring security and my config is

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
        authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().csrf().disable().formLogin().loginPage("/adminlogin").failureUrl("/adminlogin?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/dashboard")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/adminlogin?logout=true").and().exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/accessdenied");
}
```

now what i am trying to achieve that all links are accessible without any security but link start with /admin/** only allow to user with role "admin".

but rite now it allow /admin/** to everyone.

any suggestions.

i have tried many solutions from stackoverflow i.e [How to fix role in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052745/how-to-fix-role-in-spring-security) but no luck. the behavior remains same,it allows even /admin/ urls to use publicly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix role in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052745/how-to-fix-role-in-spring-security)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http
    .csrf().disable()      
    .httpBasic().and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/adminLogin").failureUrl("/adminLogin?error=true")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/dashboard")
    .usernameParameter("email")
    .passwordParameter("password")
    .and().logout()
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/adminLogin?logout=true").and().exceptionHandling()
    .accessDeniedPage("/accessdenied");
```

works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try role?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
    }
   }
```

ref : http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions-basic

Comment: i have tried this but no luck , the behavior remains same.

Comment: Did u debug which line it fails ?Change the order or remove this 
 .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()  and add line by line conditions