# Disabling csrf gives 404 for Spring boot 2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring boot 2.1.4.RELEASE and trying to figure out 401 Unauthorized error.

Below is my webconfig class

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/somepath/")

    }

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    if(securityEnabled) {
        http
                .csrf().disable()  
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/somepath/").permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint());
    }
```

In my main class i have excluded -

```
 @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Now when i try to test my api using `http://localhost:8080/somepath` then i am getting 401 unauthorized. But when i try the same endpoint with token then it works which means that authentication has not been disabled successfully. I would appreciate any help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix role in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052745/how-to-fix-role-in-spring-security)

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the order of below statements.
2. In the first statement, you are asking to have authentication for any request(all request)
3. Then you are filtering requests with pattern("/somepath/") which is not relevant as the first statement satisfied.

   ```
       .anyRequest().authenticated()
       .antMatchers("/somepath/").permitAll()
   ```
4. Remove below statement. When using permitAll it means every authenticated user, however you disabled anonymous access so that won't work.

   ```
           .anonymous().disable()
   ```

So use below configure function with rearranged order that should solve this problem.

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/somepath/")

    }

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    if(securityEnabled) {
        http
                .csrf().disable()  
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/somepath/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()


                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint());
    }
```

Comment: I tried re-ordering this but i am still getting 401 unauthorized error. Quick update in my application.properties i have servlet-context-path - server.servlet.context-path = /path1 and then my .antMatchers("/path1/somepath/").permitAll(). I am trying GET METHOD via postman - http://localhost:8080/path1/somepath and getting 401 unauthorized error

Comment: Hi Jon remove the statement         .anonymous().disable() that should solve your problem. I have edited my response to cover same.